# Getting error "class file for org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver not found"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to build my selenium project in intellij, I am getting the error

> Error:(48, 22) java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
>     class file for org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver not found.

I copied the same code into a new project and it works well there. I am not sure what is causing this issue. Below is the pom file I have used for selenium webdriver

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

The error is appearing at line where I try to initialize the chromedriver

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Here driver is of type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Comment: Please, add your whole class of test

Answer (score 0):

You have to download chromeDriver.exe and save the path location,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\your\\path\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: It is been set. I am getting the error during building the project, not during running it @Camilo Avila

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the library to class-path. One easy way to fix these type of (class not found) errors in intelliJ is:

Step 1:

- write a dummy line of code like:

```
RemoteWebDriver dummy = new  RemoteWebDriver();
```

Step 2:

- intelliJ will hint you to add the required library to class-path. Use `option + enter` to add it
  Step 3:
- Remove the dummy line of code

---

This happens because dependencies defined in pom.xml are not automatically added to the class-path.

`ChromeDriver` uses `RemoteWebDriver`. However adding the required library for `ChromeDriver` does not automatically add the library for `RemoteWebDriver`.